# Unable to switch to pop using window handles using selenium with java chrome

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, window-handles

```
public void recordings(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='menu-toggle waves-effect waves-block']/span[text()='Services']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class=' waves-effect waves-block']/span[text()='System Recordings']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary waves-effect']")).click();
        String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
        String subWindowHandler = null;

        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
```

[image]

Comment: Just try with the if condition in side the while loop this might help you




    Set<String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> itr= handles.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
    String subWindowHandler =itr.next();

    if(! parentWindowHandler.equals(subWindowHandler)){
    driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
    driver.close();
    }
    }
    driver.switchTo().window(parentWindowHandler);
    }

Comment: Would be nice if you can provide URL of the website so that we can try.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the HTML code as plain text. The screenshot is a good visual, but code is too hard to read in an image.